# C++ stop do while loop once condition is met

Tags: c++

```
do {
   cout << "Quantity  : ";
   cin >> sale->quantity;
   cout << "Unit Price: ";
   cin >> sale->unitPrice;
   cout << "Taxable   : ";
   cin >> sale->taxStatus;
} while (sale->quantity != 0);
```

When I enter `0` for `quantity`, it still asks me for `unitPrice` and `taxStatus`, and then it terminates. How could I get my loop to terminate as soon as `quantity` entered is `0`?

edit

```
> echo "" | a.out 
Sale Records 
=============
Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : Quantity  : Unit Price: Taxable   : >
```

Comment: Does your program work when you say `echo "" | ./prog`?

Comment: Yes it does work, it spit out a lot of values, I've updated OP.

Comment: Is that correct behaviour? I.e. is that how you want it to behave?

Comment: As Kerrek hints, your code doesn't check that input was available or parsable - you should read an tutorial on iostreams to learn how to check for successful parsing and `eof` conditions....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried telling it to terminate when the quality is 0?

```
cin >> sale->quantity;
if (sale->quantity == 0) break;
```

Comment: That worked, didn't know that was possible, new to C++! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can break out of the loop early by adding this check after `cin >> sale->quantity;`

```
if (sale->quantity == 0)
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to terminate the loop as soon as `quantity` entered is 0, is to put the rest of that logic inside an `if` statement.

another way is to use a `break`, but then I would change the loop to a `for(;;)`.

note that the loop continuation condition is checked only once per each loop iteration, for the `do` loop at the end of the loop body: it's not continuously checked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is

```
cout << "Quantity  : ";
cin >> sale->quantity;
while (sale->quantity != 0)
{
   cout << "Unit Price: ";
   cin >> sale->unitPrice;
   cout << "Taxable   : ";
   cin >> sale->taxStatus;
   // next iteration for Quantity
   cout << "Quantity  : ";
   cin >> sale->quantity;
}
```

but I'm not sure if you are doing anything with the sale structure with each iteration.  If so, you'll want to add that code before the comment `// next iteration for Quantity`